# SQL COUNT command

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, if-statement

```
CREATE TABLE Student_Exam(
  Exam_ID INTEGER,
  S_ID INTEGER,
  Primary Key (Exam_ID, S_ID),
  Foreign Key (Exam_ID) References Exams(Exam_ID),
  Foreign Key (S_ID) References Students(S_ID),
  Pass TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Students(
  S_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  First_Name TEXT,
  Surname TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Exams(
  Exam_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Date_Taken DATE
);
```

How can I correct this?

```
SELECT MAX(Students.S_ID) AS S_ID, **count(Pass="Yes")** AS No_of_Exams_Taken
FROM Student_Exam, Students, Exams
WHERE Students.S_ID=Student_Exam.S_ID And Exams.Exam_ID=Student_Exam.Exam_ID And (Exams.Date_Taken)>=#1/1/2010# And (Exams.Date_Taken)<=#12/31/2010#
GROUP BY Student_Exam.S_ID;
```

I would like to count the number of exams each student has passed? How is the count should be in the SELECT command?

SELECT Student.S_ID, COUNT(*) AS Final_Exam_Level
FROM Student, Exams, Student_Exam
WHERE (Student.S_ID)=Student_Exam.S_ID
And ((Exams.Exam_ID)=Student_Exam.Exam_ID)
And (Exams.Date_Taken)<=#12/31/2010#
GROUP BY Student.S_ID, Student.Course_Level
ORDER BY Student.S_ID;

Above is the correct query

Comment: Grouping and summarizing is something the report does very well, so you shouldn't do it in the report (well, you MAY need to do so, but likely not). Stop building the report and instead build a SQL SELECT that returns the data that is being summarized, and then try using that as the Recordsource for your report.

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.s_id as student_id, count(*)
FROM students s
left join student_exam se on s.s_id = se.s_id and se.pass='yes'
left join exam e on se.exam_id = e.exam_id
group by s.s_id
```

I would suggest you change pass to a non text field.  If it is just going to have yes and no then it should be boolean.

Comment: I cannot use left join or right join or any join and I would then like to combine it into another query. I am not allowed to use boolean, I am not a computer student and I am only allowed to use TEXT, NUMBER, INTEGER, DATE and TIME

Comment: Then try using an Integer with a value of 0 or 1 in that field.

Comment: becuase I am a business student and we r not allowed

Comment: As an aside, you are "doing a join" using syntax that does not use the join statement -- it is just restricted to what is called an inner join.

Comment: What @Hogan said. That is, an implicit JOIN implemented with a WHERE clause is just as much a JOIN an an explicit one that uses the word JOIN. Unless the lesson is designed to teach you about the capabilities and limitations of implicit JOINs, the restriction against using JOINs is nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

This version answers the specific question of how to count based on a condition.  As a bonus it will also provide the number of exams taken.

```
select
   s.s_id as student_id
  ,count(case when se.pass='Yes' then 1 end) as exams_passed
  ,count(*) as exams_taken
from
   Students s
   join Student_Exam se on s.s_id = se.s_id
   join Exam e on se.exam_id = e.exam_id
where
   e.date_taken between #1/1/2010# and #12/31/2010#
group by
   s.s_id
```

Based on your other comments, a version avoiding the `join` would be:

```
select
   s.s_id as student_id
  ,count(case when se.pass='Yes' then 1 end) as exams_passed
  ,count(*) as exams_taken
from
   Students s
  ,Student_Exam se
  ,Exam e
where
   s.s_id = se.s_id
   and se.exam_id = e.exam_id
   and e.date_taken between #1/1/2010# and #12/31/2010#
group by
   s.s_id
```

Or, here's a simpler version that doesn't get so fancy with `case`:

```
select
   s.s_id as student_id
  ,count(*) as exams_passed
from
   Students s
  ,Student_Exam se
  ,Exam e
where
   s.s_id = se.s_id
   and se.exam_id = e.exam_id
   and e.date_taken between #1/1/2010# and #12/31/2010#
   and se.pass = 'Yes'
group by
   s.s_id
```

Comment: count(case when Student_Exam.pass='Yes' then 1 end) as Exams_Passed. Notice that Pass is in the joint table. And I dont understand the CASE WHEN student_exam='Yes' then 1 end. But anyways I tried it and it didnt work. Do u think you can help further please?

Comment: Oops. Thanks for the correction.  The `case` expression yields `1` when the `se.pass='Yes'` condition is True, otherwise it yields `NULL`.  Count will only count the non-`NULL` rows, giving you a count of exams passed.

Comment: There are no Null rows. It is either Yes or No.

Comment: True as that may be, the `case` expression will give you `NULL` if none of the conditions are met.  A replacement using `case` would be `sum(case when se.pass='Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as exams_passed`, which does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Exam_ID S_ID Pass
1 1          YES
1 2          YES
1 3          NO
2 4          NO
2 5          YES
3 1          YES
3 2          YES
4 6          YES
5 7          NO
4 7          YES
5 9          No

Comment: I've updated my answer with a third option that doesn't get fancy with `case` expressions.  Good luck!

Comment: This error appears : Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression'sum(case when Student_Exam.Pass='Yes' then 1 else 0 end)'. I forgot to mention that am working on SQL in Microsoft Access, not sure if that has got to do with anything

Comment: Ah.  Apparently Access doesn't support `case`.  Try something like `sum(iif(Student_Exam.Pass='Yes',1,0))`.